# Problem trying to populate a text box using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

**I am trying to populate a text box with the email address of a local office contact from a database using the following Objects, Entity Framework and LINQ.
This is the LINQ that I am using:**

```
var localContactsEmail = from office in context.Offices
                         where office.Address.ToString().Equals(selectedAddress)
                         select office.OfficeContacts.Email;

tbLocalOfficeEmail.Text = localContactsEmail.ToString();
```

**If I use ToString() on localContactsEmail the text box displays this:**

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email] FROM  [dbo].[Offices] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OfficeContacts] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OfficeContactId] = [Extent2].[OfficeContactId] 
    WHERE ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address] END) = @p__linq__0) OR ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address] END IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

**If I leave off ToString() on localContactsEmail I get the following error:**

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

**Can anyone tell me why it is not returning just the email address.**

**Here are the objects.**

```
public class OfficeContact
{
     [Key]
     public int OfficeContactId { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string Email { get; set; }

     public string Phone { get; set; }

}

public class Office
{
     [Key]
     public int OfficeId { get; set; }

     public string Region { get; set; }

     public string Address { get; set; }

     public string City { get; set; }
        
     [Display(Name = "OfficeContact")]
     public virtual int OfficeContactId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("OfficeContactId")]
     public virtual OfficeContact OfficeContacts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does intellisense indicate what type `localContactsEmail` is?  Your error seems to indicate it’s an `IQueryable`, probably `IQueryable<string>`. You can probably call `.Single()` on it to get the single item in the collection, or the other variants of SingleOrDefault (no result returned), First (the SQL query is allowed to return 2+ rows), or FirstOrDefault (the query may return zero, 1, or 2+ rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localContactsEmail is IQueryable. Can you try this code:

```
var localContactsEmail = (from office in context.Offices
                         where office.Address.ToString().Equals(selectedAddress)
                         select office.OfficeContacts.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `tbLocalOfficeEmail.Text = localContactsEmail.ToString();` to

```
  if (localContactsEmail.Any())
            {
                tbLocalOfficeEmail.Text = localContactsEmail.First().ToString();
            }
```